# disable java security alerts from oracle 11g forms application

Tags: java, oracle, oracleforms, weblogic11g

I have developed one application in oracle forms 11g and it has been published on oracle middleware 11g (oracle Weblogic server 11g). In this application I am using Webutility tool as well.
whenever I am trying to run the application it gives me 3 to 4 alerts as "Do you want to run this application?". Each time we have to check "I accept the risk and want to run this application." then click on Run button. actually it is irritating for the end users. Is there any way to avoid these kinds of alerts while opening the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and deploy a Deployment Rule Set (DRS).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/deployment_rules.html